# asp.net ajax call fails with 404

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am trying to make this ajax call:

```
function Test(){
            var results = new Array();

            var emp1 = { "ID": "12", "Name": "Manas" };
            results.push(emp1);

            var emp2 = { "ID": "2", "Name": "Tester" };
            results.push(emp2);

            var postData = { empList: results };

            $.ajax({
                url: 'Sprachen/SaveEmpList',
                data: JSON.stringify(postData),
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function () {
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                },
                complete: function () {
                },
                failure: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Status: " + jqXHR.status + "; Error: " + jqXHR.responseText); // Display error message
                }
            });
        }
```

to my controller:

```
public static bool SaveEmpList(List<Employee> empList)
        {
            try
            {
                // Implement your logic to save EmpList in Database  
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log Error  
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
```

This is my base URL before I click the button to callthe Test() function

```
https://localhost:44306/Jobs/Sprachen?categoryId=handwerk&handler=UserId
```

But i am getting a 404.

How do I create the URL so that I wont get  the 404 anymore?

Answer (score 0):

this would work:

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/Jobs/Sprachen/?handler=RandomNumber",
                data: JSON.stringify({ Min: testvariable, Max: "no" }),
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
            }).done(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            })
            .fail(function (error) {
                //nothing for now
            });
```